# Parallel.For loops the same items

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have this Parallel.For code:

```
foreach (string g in allGames)
{
    eventsList.Add(game);
}

eventsList.Distinct();

Parallel.For(0, eventsList.Count, i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(eventsList[i]);
                });
```

The allGames array contains the following strings:

```
String A: Lee, Stephen - Cope, Jamie
String B: Carter, Ali - Stevens, M
String C: Dott, G - McManus, Alan
String D: Bingham, S - Liu Song
String E: Davis, Mark - Joyce, Mark
String F: Walden, R - Liu Chuang
```

My result looks like:

```
Game: Lee, Stephen - Cope, Jamie
Game: Lee, Stephen - Cope, Jamie
Game: Lee, Stephen - Cope, Jamie
Game: Lee, Stephen - Cope, Jamie
Game: Carter, Ali - Stevens, M
Game: Dott, G - McManus, Alan
Game: Bingham, S - Liu Song
Game: Davis, Mark - Joyce, Mark
Game: Walden, R - Liu Chuang
```

It seems like it goes on same iteration for 4 times (it happens many times in the code).

I confirmed that the eventsList list DOES NOT contain any duplicates, thats 100% confirmed.

Any clue how can I solve this issue to make it works only once on each element?

Thanks!

Comment: `eventsList.Distinct();` this line doesn't do much. Did you mean `eventsList = eventsList.Distinct();` ?

Comment: When doing `.Distinct()` that'll return a new object, not alter the list. Also, you seem to be adding the `game` object to the list `allGames.Count()` times (your local variable is called `g`, not `game`).

Answer (score 4):

This may be the problem - or at least it's a bug in your code:

```
eventsList.Distinct();
```

That doesn't do anything - like all other LINQ operators, it returns a new sequence, rather than modifying the existing one. Try:

```
eventsList = eventsList.Distinct().ToList();
```

I know you *say* you're 100% sure that the list doesn't contain any duplicates - but in that case you wouldn't need the distinct call, would you? Either way, it was a useless line of code.

The `Parallel.For` code you've given is fine, although it would be neater with [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee835497.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(eventsList, Console.WriteLine);
```

If that still fails, please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I fixed this, but the same error comes up! as I said, I confirmed the list (just using a debugger)

Comment: @HarisHasan: If I had a dollar for every time an OP had claimed they were 100% certain that the problem *wasn't* in X, but then it turned out to be exactly X...

Comment: @IdoLazar: Yes, you think you confirmed it - but I don't like to rule anything out, as too often I've seen people *think* they've confirmed something, but they haven't really. As I said in the answer, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help here...

Comment: @HarisHasan - Jon's right. Did you make the correction? Unless you can guarantee somewhere else that the data will always be distinct, you may need it.

Comment: When I switch the Parallel.ForEach (I changed it) to standard foreach, it works just fine, one by one, I guess it caused because of the threads.

Comment: The program is parsing an XML with strings, putting all strings in allGames, and displaying each string to the screen.

    foreach (string g in allGames)
    {
        eventsList.Add(game);
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(eventsList, eventNode =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventNode);
    });

Before the Parallel loop started, I had 6 items in my list (totally different items) and when it prints it out to the screen I see 6 items, but 4 of them are the same items.

So it does go 6 items, but its providing the same eventNode 4 times, and then goes to the next one.

Thats just weird :(

Comment: @IdoLazar: As I said, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...